# Xcode version 5.1.1 (5B1008) - run Simulator on iOS 7.0 not 7.1

Tags: ios, xcode

We have an application that had the `iOS Deployment Target` set to `iOS 7.1`. The client received some complaints that it could not run on iOS 7.0.

What I've done is change the setting to target iOS 7.0 instead of iOS 7.1. I think this should be enough for the app to work on a device with iOS 7.0. I'd like to test this out but I cannot run the Simulator on iOS 7.0, is this possible to do? Unfortunately, all devices we have available are on 7.1.

I'm not sure if there is a way to make sure it works on iOS 7.0 as well before updating the app.

**Update**

[image: Xcode's Downloads]

This is what I see when going to the Downloads section

Comment: "Development Target" or "Deployment Target" ?

Comment: Sorry about that, Deployment Target...updated the question. Thanks

Comment: The Deployment Target is the LOWEST version of iOS that you want it to run on. So when it was set to iOS 7.1 then it will only run on iOS 7.1 and newer. Setting it to 7.0 will allow it to run on 7.0 and newer.

Comment: Yep exactly thanks, I wanted to test out on an iOS 7.0 Simulator to make sure it works :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the Deployment target to 7.0 and the Base SDK to 7.1.

In order to run on older simulator you need to get them from older versions of Xcode. You can download Xcode 5 here: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode

After installing Xcode5 you can copy the simulators to you newest version of Xcode.

From

```
/Applications/Xcode-Old.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk
```

To

```
/Applications/Xcode-New.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk
```

Then you should be able to select older simulators in the newest Xcode. If it works, then you can delete the old Xcode.

Comment: Yes that's the way I have set up the settings. Going to Xcode's Preferences and Downloads, I only have available iOS 6.1 Simulator, no iOS 7.0 Simulator :/